# cordova inappbrowser Error: TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, auth0

Working on using Auth0's Lock V9 in Ionic with Angular 1.x . I'm avoiding upgrading at the moment as it wouldn't be production level of sturdyness.

My question is this, I'm running Auth0 perfectly in Ionic Serve locally, logs in and redirects perfectly. Yet when I run it on android I get the Following error

Error in Success callbackId: InAppBrowser1651651898 : TypeError: callback is not a function

As you can see, the authentication is working, though I think the problem is in Cordova's inappbrowser. I've tried on both a live reload and non live version on android without luck. I've had to downgrade my lock version as the Auth0 10 wrapper for angular does not seem to work as well either.

Anyway, I'd be grateful for any input. Been banging my head off a desk trying to sort this issue out as its killing my time this week.

Thanks all,
Kieran